# Meowing and running

Tags: cats

I have an adopted black cats that doesn't trust me much.

He stays at least 2 meters from me when in the same room and he usually stays in the same room as me only if I'm laying down. If I stand up he runs away at top speed.

However he meows a lot!

Since cats only meows to communicate with humans I'm quite confused!!!

Any idea what's happening. Should I give him attention or not?

Edit: Not looking for answers to how keep him from running or getting him to trust me. I know that this will take time.

What I want to know is why does he meows so much since I'm the only human in the household and he runs when I get near.